# How to tail follow file but only output new entries to the log

Tags: file, go, tail

I'm trying to do something similar to `tail -f` with go (open a file and keep tracking file changes) but only start printing the changes from the end of the file. I need to seek the end of the file but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm looking at io.Seeker but haven't found a way.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/nxadm/tail"
)

var logFile = "/var/log/syslog"

func main() {
    t, err := tail.TailFile(logFile, tail.Config{
     Follow: true, 
     // Location: // somehow indicate it's the end of the file?
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for line := range t.Lines {
        fmt.Println(line.Text)
    }
}
```

What is missing in the code above to jump to the end of the file?

This is the [source](https://github.com/nxadm/tail/blob/master/examples/01-tailAndPrint/main.go) where I got the example above.

Comment: I'm not quite follow your question: if you're using an external package to `tail -f` a file, then use the appropriate feature of the API of that package _if it has it._ If it does not, you basically have to either find a better package or roll another implementation yourself, and in the latter case you won't have troubles seeking to the end of the file as `*os.File`—what is returned by `os` functions for opening files—100% supports seeking.

Comment: @kostix I'm new to golang, so I asked the question exactly to know if I'm misunderstanding the library or if there's some implementation that already jumps to the end. If you know a better package or rolled your own solution, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for SeekInfo on the repo and found a solution: `Location: &tail.SeekInfo{Offset: 0, Whence: io.SeekEnd}`.

Full example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"

    "github.com/nxadm/tail"
)

var logFile = "/var/log/syslog"

func main() {
    t, err := tail.TailFile(logFile, tail.Config{
     Follow: true, 
     Location: &tail.SeekInfo{Offset: 0, Whence: io.SeekEnd}, // <- line changed
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for line := range t.Lines {
        fmt.Println(line.Text)
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the code not on the API but on some random file on the repository. I even put the Location commented on the initial code because I read the API. I just wanted that one liner that is not really engineering.

Comment: @kostix what an incredibly rude and uncalled-for comment, reported

Comment: @SDee Yeah, could assume the docs could be better (I missed the API link and went to the examples), could assume I went to the code to understand. But the only assumption is that I copy pasted something.

But yeah, I could be a better software engineer if next time I'm going through the docs I don't try and jump to what I want :)

Comment: @SDee, I'm afraid it's a problem of written communication (as opposed to in-person). At my $dayjob, I lead a team, and I assure you the problem of not reading the docs and not trying (enough) to work out a solution is unfortunately common for newfangled devs (and even to some claiming they have middle "grade"). So my comment may sound harsh but it was absolutely sincere: I tried to highlight what could have been improved in the approach. I think should I have said that to Artur in person, it would sound pretty… I dunno… normal. Hope he perceived it the way I intended. If not, I apologize :-\

Comment: @kostix I perceived you assumed I didn't read the documentation. I'm used to readmes that have an emphasized API heading which is not the case. That's why I missed the link. In any case, no worries.